# Determine the Tangent Space of a Submanifold

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Let $M:=\{(x_1,x_2,x_3)\in\mathbb{R}^3\colon x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_3^2=x_1+x_2+x_3-1=0\}$ be a given submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^3$. I want to compute $T_p(M)$ at $p=(1,1,-1)$.

My definition of the tangential is the following:

Let $Y$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^l$ and $f\in C^1(X,Y)$. Then the linear map

$T_pf\colon T_pX\longrightarrow T_{f(p)}Y, \ (p,v)\mapsto (f(p),\partial f(p)v)$

is called the tangential of $f$ at the point $p$.

Furthermore, i have that for a $(n-l)$-dimensional submanifold $M:=f^{-1}(c)$ where c is a regular value, that $T_pM=\ker(T_pf)=(T_pf)^{-1}(c)$.

What I could do is the following:

I set $\Phi\colon \mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow \mathbb{R},\ (x_1,x_2,x_3)\mapsto ( x_1^2+x_2^2-2x_3^2,x_1+x_2+x_3-1)$

and already know that $\Phi^{-1}(0)$ is the submanifold in question.

I now need the matrix for $T_pf$ and I struggle to construct it. The Jakobi Matrix of $\Phi$ is no problem. Do I just have to compute $f(p),\partial f(p)$ and put it in the form $(f(p),\partial f(p)v)$ like mentioned above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f=x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2$ and $g=x_1+x_2+x_3-1$.

Being the intersection of the two 2-D Manifolds F given by  $f=0$ and G, given by $g=0$, the intersection (call it C) is a 1-D submanifold of the both of them. The point $p$ lies in C and we want to know a tangent vector to C at $p$ and that would define the tangent space entirely (since it is a 1-D space, knowing any vector in it fully specifies it). Note that because C lies in both F and G, a tangent vector to C at $p$ must be perpendicular to normals to both F and G (this tangent vector belongs in both tangent spaces $T_pF$ and $T_pG$). In other words, the cross product $$\nabla f \times \nabla g$$ must be in the tangent space of C at $p$.

The computation of the vector is trivial. So I’ll leave it to you to take it from here.

**Second approach**

To use your defintions of the tangent space (kernel of the differential map). The tangent space of F at P is $(Df)^{-1}(0)$ and likewise for G. The tangent space of C is $  (Df)^{-1}(0) \cap (Dg)^{-1}(0) $. Noting that for $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$, at the point $p$, $Df$ is given by the matrix $[2,2,4]$ and $Dg$ by the Jacobian $[1,1,1]$.  So, we are looking for tangent vectors of the form $\vec{t}=(u,v,w)$ that satisfy the matrix equation.

$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 &1&1\\2&2&4\end{array}\right] \left[\begin{array}{cc}u \\v\\w\end{array}\right]= \left[\begin{array}{cc}0\\0\end{array}\right] $$

That is, vectors proportional to $\vec{t}=(-1,1,0)$ make up the tangent space at $p$.  You can write down the coordinates of the tangent line if you want as $\vec{p}+s\vec{t}$ where you let the parameter $s$ take all values on the real line.

Comment: I "don't know" normal vectors yet. If you had to use just my definition straightforward, how would the matrix look like?

Comment: It can be done with your definition too. Let me edit it into the answer.

Comment: You should probably add to your answer, that the derivatives were all taken at the point $p$.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta Good idea.